# glGetString(GL_EXTENSIONS) vs wglGetExtensionsStringEXT

Tags: opengl

I have thought that WGL extensions list can be retrieved only using `wglGetExtensionsStringEXT`. During debugging I have noticed that gl extensions list retrieved using `glGetString(GL_EXTENSIONS)` contains
`WGL_EXT_swap_control`. I'm suprised. Is it an exception ? Could explain that ? I expect that `glGetString(GL_EXTENSIONS)` will not return any WGL extension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [WGL_EXT_extensions_string](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/extensions/EXT/WGL_EXT_extensions_string.txt) function does state that implementations can advertise WGL extensions in the OpenGL extension string. This is due to the fact that, before this extension came into being, that's how WGL extensions worked: they were specified as part of the OpenGL extension string. So implementations would still advertise those extensions in their OpenGL strings.

Indeed, the WGL_EXT_extensions_string function *specifically* mentions WGL_EXT_swap_interval, since it (among others) predated WGL_EXT_extensions_string.

Comment: What about glXQueryExtensionsString ? Does glGetString(GL_EXTENSIONS) may return some glx extensions ?

Comment: @Irbis: I don't know; you'd have to look through the various GLX stuff.